# SQLITE DDL USING AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: sqlite

Is is possilbe to have SQLITE DDL in this case ( LineNum is AUTO INCREMENT column is part of a TransDate column). The AUTO INCREMENT VALUES are re-used if i insert the row with new daily transaction entries.  the AUTO INCREMENT column (LineNum) will generate sequence from the values 1 when new transactions inserted. See example below.

```
TransDate   LineNum GL_Number
20141011    1   2163370000
20141011    2   2163370000
20141011    3   2163370000
20141011    4   2163370000
20141011    5   2163370000
20141011    6   2163370000
20141011    7   2163370000
20141011    8   2163370000
20141011    9   2163370000
20141011    10  2163370000
20141012    1   2163370000
20141012    2   2163370000
20141012    3   2163370000
20141012    4   2163370000
20141012    5   2163370000
20141012    6   2163370000
20141012    7   2163370000
20141012    8   2163370000
20141012    9   2163370000
20141012    10  2163370000
```

Answer (score 1):

No; in SQLite, [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) works only if the column alone is the primary key.

To compute the daily line number, you would have to count how many rows for the same day there already are:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM MyTable
WHERE TransDate = 20141013
```

Comment: Sorry I not clear with the alternative solution. if you could please guide how you are going approach and solving this problem.

Comment: This query computes the line number to be used for the next insertion on that date.

Comment: the number records can be varied on a given date. let say this query computes 14 records in the count function + 1 is 15. This means LineNum is starting at 15 for the next insertion on that date. I want it reused the LineNum starting at 1. I am not with you at the moment.

Comment: You want the number to restart at 1 only when the date changes. With a new date, this query will not find any existing rows.

Comment: You have not understood what I wrote. With `WHERE TransDate = 20141012`, this query returns `11`. With `WHERE TransDate = 20141013`, this query returns `1`.